# Access query with IN clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Want to use a IN-clause in Access (2010). The results are however incorrect. The simplified original query looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmountOnce
FROM Invoices
WHERE (((Invoices.[ClientID])  In (SELECT A.ClientID FROM Invoices A GROUP BY  A.ClientID HAVING COUNT(A.ClientID)=1 )));
```

The problem is that not all records are processed (having a count > 1). Even the following fails:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmountOnce
FROM Invoices
WHERE (((Invoices.[ClientID])  In (SELECT A.ClientID FROM Invoices A )));
```

where the condition is "void". The second query gives an incorrect result too. Removing the condition works fine. Negating the condition (NOT IN) gives an empty result. What is wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is table name in subquery after IN clause ? INVOICE or INVOICES or something else

Comment: First thought: Are there records where ClientID is null?

Comment: Why so complicated? You are referring to just one table, so why use IN? You can use COUNT.

Comment: Right, there is one record with a ClientID = NULL. Sorry!